# Change parent's height to child's height

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jquery plugin dotdotdot to create '... Read More >>' after a block of text.
When the user clicks on the link ('read more>>') the div must expand so the whole text is visible. First part works great but I can't figure out the second part.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#dot3').dotdotdot({
                after: 'a#test'

            });
        }); 
<style type="text/css" media="all">
        div.example {
            padding: 0 0 150px 0;
        }
        div.example:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
        div.r {
            width: 275px;
        }
        div.box {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            height: 160px;
            padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
            overflow:visible;
        }
</style>
<div class="example">
            <div class="r">
                <div class="box after" id="dot3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                    <a href="#" id="test" onClick="">Read more &raquo;</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the second part, the div to expand? Can you also explain the title a bit more?

Comment: The lorem text is shown like this 'Lorem ips... Read More >>'. This is done by the dotdotdot plugin en the css setting. If the read more>> link is clicked, the whole text should be shown. I tried to change the height of div.box to auto but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the destroy, and resize the div.
Try

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    var div = $('#dot3');
    div.trigger('destroy');
    div.css("height", "auto");
});
```

[Here is fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RgHRs/16/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thnx!